# How to make predictions with multiple input model in tensorflow (without model.predict)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

```
noise = Input(shape=(100,))
label = Input(shape=(10,))

x = Dense(128)(noise)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = LeakyReLU()(x)

y = Dense(128)(label)
y = BatchNormalization()(y)
y = LeakyReLU()(y)

x = concatenate([x, y], axis=-1)
x = Dense(256)(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = LeakyReLU()(x)
x = Dense(512)(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = LeakyReLU()(x)
x = Dense(1024)(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = LeakyReLU()(x)
x = Dense(784, activation='tanh')(x)
image = Reshape((28, 28, 1))(x)

model = Model(inputs=[noise, label], outputs=[image])
```

Here is my code to build **multiple input model**. In this case, `model.predict(x=[noise, label])` seems to be used to make predictions of the model.

I think `model.predict(x)` can be replaced by `model(x)`. So I tried `model([noise, label])`, but it doesn't work. It seems to continue to expand the model. Is there any way to make `model(x)` method work?
Please help. (I can not use `model.predict(x=[noise, label])`

Comment: what is the issue with `model([noise, label])`? That should normally work

Comment: `model.predict` function is created to predict. I don't think you can make predictions without `model.predict`. Why can't you use `model.predict(x=[noise, label])`?

Comment: Thanks for your attentions. If I use "model.predict()", I can't use tf.gradienttape().... please look  this(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62101036/trying-to-train-cgan-with-mnist-data-but-got-this-error-attributeerror-zipdata)